# installing SubVersion on Linux

Tags: java, svn, jre

I want to install Subversion Edge on Linux. I've downloaded `CollabNetSubversionEdge-1.3.3_linux-x86.tar.gz` from [here](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/linux.html) and I'm following the instruction from [here](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/csvn/action/setupcsvn.html)

When I execute `bin/csvn start` on the terminal, I'm getting this error:

> Unable to start CSVN Console: no Java executable found
> Please make sure the variable JAVA_HOME is defined in your environment

I've already ensured that JRE is installed by doing the following:

```
>> locate 'bin/java'
/usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre/bin/java
*/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/openoffice.org/ure/bin/javaldx
```

I've made the necessary changes with the instructions from [here](http://ice.he.net/%7Ehedden/jrelinux.html#check_if_JRE_installed) and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/)

I've changed the `JAVA_PATH` and `JRE_PATH` to `/usr/local/bin/java` which is a softlink to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/bin/java` which I'm confident is the absolute link to the `JRE` installed.

After making those changes, I've restarted my computer. I tried to execute `bin/csvn start`, but I am still getting the same error.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable?

Comment: also, what is output of `java -version`

Comment: hi, echo $JAVA_HOME = /usr/local/bin/java. And the java -version is [root@localhost ~]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.7.10) (rhel-1.20.b17.el5-i386)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

> I've changed the JAVA_PATH and JRE PATH to ...

Reread those instructions *carefully*, especially the ones in the second link.  The environment variables that need to be set are "JAVA_HOME" and "PATH".  (Not "JAVA_PATH" or "JRE PATH" or some other random name.)

And make sure that you "export" the variables, otherwise they will be just shell variables and not environment variables.

Hint: running the command `export` with no arguments will list all of the environment variables that are in effect for the current shell ... and commands run from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to install the sun jdk, you can do so by uninstalling first the gcj and the openjdk. The procedure will vary depending on your distro.

But after that (also depending on your distro) you will need to install the sun jdk.
In ubuntu, for example you have to do something like:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jdk
```

You will find detailed instructions in:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-ubuntu-linux-install-configure-jdk-jre/

Answer (score 0):

I found the path to the JRE was enough. I didn't have to dive all the way down to the actual Java binary.

```
su - csvn
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
/svn/ci/csvn/bin/csvn start
```

Answer (score 0):

What eventually worked for me is setting propper **JAVA_HOME** in csvn's config file, located in **csvn/data/csvn.conf**

```
# Java environment
# Minimum version: "1.6", etc. Leave empty if no minimum required
# JAVA_HOME_CONF points to a file whose first line is exported as the JAVA_HOME when
# the environment var is not found
JAVA_REQUIRED=true
JAVA_REQUIRED_VERSION=1.7
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```